# computing standard deviation without mean produces illegal result!

Tags: standard-deviation, machine-precision

I would like to compute STD in one-pass, without first computing the mean:
Hence, I decided to use the following [formula][1]:

```
 std dev = sqrt [(B - A^2/N)/N]
```

where

`A` is the sum of the data values;

`B` is the sum of the squared data values;

`N` is the number of data values.

And I am using float precision  (cannot use double).

However, It happens that sometimes when `B` is very close to the value of `A^2/N`, I am getting a negative values for `(B - A^2/N)/N`, which doesn't happen when doing it the straightforward way.

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

Comment: Could you please define your problem more rigorously without referring to an external website. For example, what do $A$, $B$ and $N$ mean.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. In your formula, $A = \sum_i x_i$ which is the mean times $N$. So you are effectively using the mean after all. Your problem occurs due to cancellation of significant digits and rounding, which may happen with this formula when $N$ is large. For example if the data come from the R formula $x = 10^6 - runif(10^6)/100$, the formula you are proposing to use  gives a wrong answer to all significant digits. The formula therefore should **not** be used.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://pic.plover.com/MISC/symbols.pdf) to format math expressions on this site.  A good way to start is by putting `$` signs (and not backquotes) around math expressions.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks; your explanation sounds good to me; I also suspected quantization, but wasn't sure.